# Count ip repeat in log from bash

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, multidimensional-array

bash as I can tell from the repetition of an IP within a log through a specific search?

By example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Log line: [Sat Jul 04 21:55:35 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.39] Access denied with status code 403.

grep "status\scode\s403" /var/log/httpd/custom_error_log | while read line ; do

    pattern='^\[.*?\]\s\[error\]\s\[client\s(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\].*?403'
    [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]

    res_remote_addr="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.${BASH_REMATCH[3]}.${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"

    echo "Remote Addr: $res_remote_addr"

done
```

I need to know the end results obtained a few times each message 403 ip, if possible sort highest to lowest.

By example output:

```
200.200.200.200 50 times.
200.200.200.201 40 times.
200.200.200.202 30 times.
... etc ...
```

This we need to create an html report from a monthly log of apache in a series of events (something like awstats).

Comment: Something like `awk '/code 403/ {print $8}' error.log | sort | uniq -c |sort -n`? If it suits you, I can write it as an answer with explanation what exactly it does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are better ways. following is my proposal, which should be more readable and easier to maintain:

```
grep -P -o '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' log_file | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1 -r -n
```

output should be in a form of:

```
count1 ip1
count2 ip2
```

update:

filter only 403:

```
grep -P -o '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?=.*403)' log_file | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1 -r -n
```

notice that a look ahead would suffice.

Comment: But log have status code 200 and 403, need only 403 status, how match only ....*(ip).*... ? use conditional $1, $2?

Comment: 40 Seconds to process 1GB log file :D

Comment: @WHK sorry about the typo. about the status code, i am not sure about the log format so i can't really clarify this. but you can apply look behind or ahead if you want to. such that you can filter only the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

If log file is in the format as mentioned in question, the best is to use `awk` to filter out the status code needed plus output only the IP. Then use the `uniq` command to count each occurence:

`awk '/code 403/ {print $8}' error.log | sort | uniq -c |sort -n`

In `awk`, we filter by regexp `/code 403/` and then for matching lines we print the 8th value (values are separated by whitespace), which is the IP.

Then we need to sort the output, so that the same IPs are one after another - this is requirement of the `uniq` program.

`uniq -c` prints each unique line from input only once - and preceded by the number of occurences. Finnaly we sort this list numericaly to get the IPs sorted by count.

Sample output (first is no. of occurences, second is IP):

> 1 1.1.1.1
>   10 2.2.2.2
>   12 3.3.3.3

Comment: it is not the exact format, I just need to solve the example for others to obtain the same log data uniquely, the actual format is much longer and more complex: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs , out log like this: http://pastebin.com/Q88xJM3y and I want to create a script that reflects the data in an html report, but the above example enough for me to go my way.